# Sign up form text shows white with a white background

Tags: css, forms, dreamweaver, sign

I have a sign up form on a website that I am developing using dreamweaver. The input text and background text are both showing as white (or not showing!) even though the page text is set at #0000CC.  See it here: www.betterlifecoaching.co.uk (it is still work in progress)
How can I overcome this?
The sign up script is:

```
<style type="text/css">
.link,
 #SignUp .signupframe {
  color: #0033CC;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
 .link {
  text-decoration: none;
  }
 #SignUp .signupframe {
  border: 1px solid #282FFF;
  background: #ABB4BA;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.icontact.com/icp/loadsignup.php/form.js?c=660346&l=7202&f=567"></script>
<a class="link" href="http://www.icontact.com"><font size="2">Email Marketing You Can Trust</font></a>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have `INPUT` defined in this part of the CSS

```
body, th, td, input, textarea, select (line 23)
{
color: #ffffff;
text-align: left;
}
```

Remove it, and all will be groovy!